# How to make my DVB-T/FM Tuner work ?

Tags: hardware, tv, tv-tuner, dvb

I just purchased a DVB-T/FM Tuner card "AverMedia H830 Hybrid USB" by Avermedia (07ca:0830).

Apparently I don't have any DVB-T signal where I live (Or I just can't figure out how to use this 'femon' tool).

Anyways I'm trying to make this card actually work, meaning that I'm looking for an app that will give me the ability to watch FM TV alongside Radio and DVB-T like the Windows version does and I just can't find something like that.

I downloaded Me-TV, no use, Israel is not included as well as no FM support.
I see that my only logical way to solve this problem is to utilize MythTV, although a wonderful app I'm not sure I need such a complicated software...

Thank you all for your help in advance!

Kind regards,
Yaron Shahrabani.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To know if you can get a DVB-T signal in your country, [have a look to this nice **map**](https://askubuntu.com/a/123930/32413).
- If yes, I suggest you to follow [this answer to test it with **VLC**](https://askubuntu.com/a/20213/32413) and create your `channels.conf` file.
- Then once you know it works, you can chose an application to watch TV like **Me-TV**, **Kaffeine** or [any other applications listed in this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/2936/32413).

Note 1: till 12.04, Me-TV was working fine for me, now I use **Kaffeine**.
Note 2: scanning with Kaffeine is the most simple method for me.
Note 3: you can re-use your `channels.conf` file from VLC for Me-TV.

Comment: And how do I watch FM TV (not DVB-T)?

Comment: @Yaron I do not know for FM TV. I assume that it is more or less the same thing: Plug your tuner card, and then check if it is usable with your TV software (like Kaffeine), if not it might be because you have not the right driver.