# No useful DVB-T card found

Tags: 12.04, installation, tv, dvb-t

I am using **Ubuntu 12.04** with *3.2.0-26 kernel* and I just added a **DVB-T card**. I installed the **media_build** as [shown in this page](http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_Obtain,_Build_and_Install_V4L-DVB_Device_Drivers). After that the *Restricted Drivers* appeared on the screen I installed the firmware for DVB Cards.

**lsusb** shows: `Bus 002 Device 005: ID 048d:9005 Integrated Technology Express, Inc.` Which is my card.

**lsmod** shows these things regarding dvb:

```
dvb_usb_it913x         22173  0     
dvb_usb                32369  1 dvb_usb_it913x    
dvb_core              110010  1 dvb_usb    
rc_core                26343  2 dvb_usb_it913x,dvb_usb
```

Nevertheless there is no `/dev/dvb` on my system and **Kaffeine** does not find the TV turner.

How can I install my TV Card?

Comment: Just done that. It is 12.04

Answer (score 0):

According to **LinuxTV**, this is supported from kernel **3.3** onwards:

[LinuxTV.org > DVB-T USB Devices/Full](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/DVB-T_USB_Devices/Full)

> ITE Inc.  | Generic 9005 Device   | **✔ Yes, in kernel since 3.3**    |   USB2.0  | **048d:9005**

Answer (score 0):

- Take a look here:

  http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/DVB-T_USB_Devices
- You could also try looking here:

  http://www.mythtvtalk.com/forum/
- Check the following drivers for additional DVB devices (s2-liplianin):

  https://pikacode.com/liplianin/

  http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/S2-liplianin
- Drivers for Elgato devices:

  http://breiti.cc/2011/03/enabling-support-for-elgato-eye-tv-sat-in-ubuntu-10-10/
  http://www.drbreinlinger.de/

  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1383823
- If you've /dev/dvb device configured, then check your file permissions, see:
  https://bugs.launchpad.net/me-tv/+bug/619530
- Other links:

  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1015387
  http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.drivers.video-input-infrastructure/15000
  http://www.spin.de/forum/117/-/40b3
- See also related issue:

  [How to make my DVB-T/FM Tuner work ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121632/how-to-make-my-dvb-t-fm-tuner-work)