# Any software to run Tv tuner USB in Ubuntu 12.04..? If anyone know about it then please suggest me

Tags: 12.04, installation, mythtv, tv-tuner, ubuntu-tv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What software is available to use TV tuner card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2936/what-software-is-available-to-use-tv-tuner-card)

I have use Intex TV Tuner USB. I want software to use it on Ubuntu 12.04 .Can anyone know about it? Please suggest me.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many software's that allow you to watch TV on Ubuntu, like TV with **Kaffeine**, TV with **Me-TV** ,TV with **VLC**, **TVtime**, **MythTV**, **mplayer**, Gnome's own **DVB Daemon**. You could refer to this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2936/what-software-is-available-to-use-tv-tuner-card) for downloads and installation instructions.

Comment: I install Me-TV,but nothing to happen.which one is best and easy for install and configure?

Comment: I see most people liked VLC, you can give a try to it. here is the link http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html